# UIActivityIndicator not showing instantly

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

For some reason i can't get activity indicator show up instantly. Maybe anyone could see why?

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
spinner.center = self.view.center; 
_active = spinner;
[self.view addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
@try {

    [self connectToServerUsingStream:ip portNo:port];
    NSString *text = @"test";
    const uint8_t *str =
    (uint8_t *) [text cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [self writeToServer:str];

}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
}
```

The spinner only shows up then connection to server was made, before that it doesn't show. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably your call to server is running in main thread and it is blocking the UI.

Comment: Well yes, i do not have call to server in seperate thread. But shouldn't the spinner be executed before connecting to server?

Comment: use NStimer between start animating and called service url. and put time of around 0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below updated code. I think it will work.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
spinner.center = self.view.center; 
 _active = spinner; 
[self.view addSubview:spinner]; 
[spinner startAnimating]; 
[self performSelector:@selector(performTask) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];

- (void)performTask {
     @try {
         [self connectToServerUsingStream:ip portNo:port];
         NSString *text = @"test";
         const uint8_t *str =
         (uint8_t *) [text cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
         [self writeToServer:str];

     }
     @catch (NSException * e) {
         NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
     } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that sure did work as expected, I will mark this as accepted answer. But could you explain a little bit your answer, just to understand everything?

Comment: The spinner will not start spinning until you process the event and returned to the run loop. The way around this is to ask the run loop to finish things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code

```
[spinner performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startAnimating) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:TRUE];
```

instead of..

```
[spinner startAnimating];
```

Comment: Result is the same, it show's up only after connection was made.

Answer (score 0):

This  lines after `[spinner startAnimating];` method blocks the main thread that is why the activity is not showing.

Please change that code like:

```
dispatch_queue_t taskQ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(taskQ, ^{
   @try
   {

     [self connectToServerUsingStream:ip portNo:port];
     NSString *text = @"test";
     const uint8_t *str =
     (uint8_t *) [text cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
     [self writeToServer:str];
   }
   @catch (NSException * e)
   {
     NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
   }
});
```